# Presenting multiple WKInterfaceController(in page base navigation) cause extra black space on top in watchOS4.

Tags: swift, watchos, xcode9, watchos-4

The application was running well before watchOS4 but in watchOS4 there is extra black space is visible on top of WKInterfaceController. This case happens in present WKInterfaceController only but seems working fine if I try to push WKInterfaceController.

Case 1 :

```
self.presentController(withNames: ["XYZ", "ABC"], contexts: nil)
```

See below image there is extra bar below the title.

[image]

Case 2:

```
self.pushController(withName: "XYZ", context: nil)
```

Working fine in push method(no extra space in watchOS4).

[image]

PS: I have tried new present method also:

```
self.presentController(withNamesAndContexts: [(name: "XYZ", context: [:] as AnyObject)])
```

> Also if I am trying to present single interface controller then it
>   works perfect, only cause when in I am trying to present multiple
>   interface controllers(in the page).

Comment: There wasn't any changes in that specific API according to the documentation, so this seems like a bug. Most probably this isn't the cause of the issue, but if you are presenting a single controller, why not use `presentController(withName:context:)`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor i am presenting 2 controllers, but just for here i have removed one.  i am using like   self.presentController(withNames: ["SleepDetail", "SleepSelectionIC"], contexts: nil)

Comment: @DávidPásztor also my all presented interface controllers have the same issue. push interface controller working fine.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

We have contacted Apple regarding that issue. Thay told us that it's a bug in watchOS and will be resolved soon.

**PS: Don't waste your code level support for this issue.**

Comment: Even, I have requested them for code level support.

Comment: We had requested before a month but still no update on watchOS, they just told us that "it's from their side". I suggest don't waste your code level support.